# Creating a search box in dreamweaver for website PHP

Tags: php, mysql, dreamweaver

im creating a website and within the website there will be a search box that will let you search for items on your website. I have code but i keep getting an error message.

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';

$search = $_POST['search']."*";

$search_query = $link->prepare("SELECT name FROM products WHERE MATCH(name) 
AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE)")
$search_query->bind_param('s', $search);
$search_query->execute();
$search_query->store_result();

$search_rows = $search_query->num_rows;
$search_query->bind_result($product_name);

if($search_rows > 0){
    while($search_query->fetch()){
        echo "Your search returned $search_rows results";
        echo $product_name."<br>";
    }
} else { echo "Your search returned no results, sorry :("; }
```

is it possible to run a search using a mysql query from the database to return searches??

Any advice would be deeply appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: My advice is to Stop using dreamweaver and use a real IDE xD it's just slightly better than frontpage. Dreamweaver was somehow useful in the old days when we were learning to do pages with tables xD

Answer (score 0):

The error is most probably because of your syntax.

```
$search_query->store_result();
$search_rows = $search_query->num_rows;
$search_query->bind_result($product_name);
```

Here, you are first trying to store the results and later binding the results to variable `$product_name` which leads to the said error.

The [`bind_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) states:

> Note that all columns must be bound after `mysqli_stmt_execute()` and prior to calling `mysqli_stmt_fetch()`. Depending on column types bound variables can silently change to the corresponding PHP type.

Answer (score 0):

That code needs some work.

That loop looks flawed. Try something like this:

```
echo "Your search returned $search_rows results";
while($search_query->fetch()){
   echo $product_name . "<br>";
}
```